# kcachegrind showing my memcpy is unaligned

Tags: c++, sse, libc

Using g++ to compile a function that uses `memcpy` and in `kcachegrind` it's showing up as using `__memcpy_sse2_unaligned`.

Is there a way for `memcpy` to use an aligned version?

Update 1: This is how I create the two buffers

```
int* dstArr = new int [0x10000];
int* srcArr = new int [0x10000];
```

Comment: Probably by making sure that the buffers you copy to and from are guaranteed to be aligned, in a way the compiler would recognize it.  How do you create the buffers now? What does the call look like in your code?

Comment: Updated adding buffer creation code.

Comment: On most systems and compilers, the underlying allocator should return an align address when allocating memory. However, the compiler might not be so certain it seems, so it does the safe thing and call the built-in function optimized for unaligned copying. And we don't know if that function checks for alignment and handles the case where both buffers are aligned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name `__memcpy_sse2_unaligned` does not mean what you think it does. In fact, it is just a version of `memcpy` that uses SSE2 with unaligned accesses (on modern/large CPUs, the penalty for unaligned accesses is generally lower than the penalty of forcing alignment in software).

Your compiler does not think it has the smarts to optimize such a large `memcpy` itself and the amd64 ABI does not provide a `memcpy` symbol that promises alignment (like `__aeabi_memcpy4` and `__aeabi_memcpy8` in ARMEABI).